# xtitle & bspwm - title showing as 0x1234567

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and have opted to use bspwm, which I use on other laptops on other distros.

I have a simple little window which shows me the title of my nodes and allows me to switch to the quickly (for monospace desktops mostly).

On Ubuntu, when I try to us =e xtitle to get the name of a node it gives me the

```
/usr/bin/bspc query -N -n .window
```

> 0x01200002
> 0x02800029
> 0x01C0002C
> 0x03800003
> 0x04A00459
> 0x03A00006
> 0x03C00003
> 0x01E00003

```
 xtitle 0x01200002
```

> title = 0x01200002
> icon  = 0x01200002

Has anyone else seen this before & managed to resolve it. As I say this configuration works for me elsewhere but this is the only time I've tried it on Ubuntu.

Thanks all.

Edit - to add to this, xprop seems to be able to work out the title

> WM_NAME(COMPOUND_TEXT) = "Google — Mozilla Firefox"
> _NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Google — Mozilla Firefox"

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a solution using xtitle that is still not working for me, however I've achieved the same results using xprop

Sample to get the Window Name for a node

```
xprop -id "0x054000DF" WM_NAME | cut -d\" -f 2
```